# Failed to share file using cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am trying to share a backup file `*.bkp` using cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
in my ionic project , using any file manager is success sharing the file. but inside using myapp failed..

I already try this code from [**SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin**](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

```
import { File, SocialSharing } from 'ionic-native';

export class Filemanager {
        constructor(
        public _BackPress: BackPress,
        public toastCtrl: ToastController,
        public viewCtrl: ViewController,
        public alertCtrl: AlertController,
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams) {

                   let path ="file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/sample/Bocaue_Caingin_-08082017082411.bkp"
                   SocialSharing.share(null,null, path ).then(data => {

                    }).catch(data => {
                      console.log('catch> error ',data)
                      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                        message: 'Share File Failed!',
                        duration: 2500
                      });
                      toast.present();

                    });

      }
}
//the console log result
//catch> error  false
```

My objective is to share to file via shareitapp, or on messenger as an attachment

Heres my Package.json

```
{
    "name": "ionic-hello-world",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
        "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",  
        "angular2-moment": "^1.1.0", 
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.7",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.6",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3", 
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.1.8",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",  
        "ionic-angular": "3.5.2",
        "ionic-native": "2.9.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",       
        "rxjs": "5.4.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [],
    "description": "project_name: An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {}, 
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Any console errors? Can you show your `constructor` code too?

Comment: I updated my Question.

Comment: Can you show the `package.json` file?

Comment: I added my package.json in my question

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 issues with your implementation.

1. You're using very OLD native dependency.You must update it to latest `"@ionic-native/core": "3.13.1",`.[**Offical**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json) `package.json` file.
2. After that, you can easily implement it using the `Ionic native` plugin as shown below.

Here is the [**official doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/).

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';

constructor(private socialSharing: SocialSharing) { }

// Check if sharing via email is supported
this.socialSharing.canShareViaEmail().then(() => {
  // Sharing via email is possible
}).catch(() => {
  // Sharing via email is not possible
});
```

Comment: I Did this versioning intentionally , because using the full versioning of  ionic3 it has issue in performance of Sqlite .

Comment: But still the version of the plugin is up to date not is old version

Comment: That is the recommended way of using Native plugins.If you don't like it then you have to face this kind of destiny and more in the future.No one can help to you.I'm also using SQLite with latest ionic.But I cannot see any performance issue with it.If you have such issue then you must open a ticket for it on their git repository.